# Construction of const object

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

C++11 §12.1/14:

> During the construction of a const object, if the value of the object or any of its subobjects is accessed through an lvalue that is
>   not obtained, directly or indirectly, from the constructor’s this
>   pointer, the value of the object or subobject thus obtained is
>   unspecified.  [Example:

```
struct C;
void no_opt(C*);

struct C {
    int c;
    C() : c(0) { no_opt(this); }
};

const C cobj;

void no_opt(C* cptr) {
    // value of cobj.c is unspecified
    int i = cobj.c * 100;
    cptr->c = 1;
    // value of cobj.c is unspecified
    cout << cobj.c * 100 << '\n';
}
```

Compiling the above example outputs `100`. My question is why is the value of `cobj.c` should be unspecified when the initialization list sets it to `0` before entering constructor? How is this behavior different in case if a non-const object is used?

Comment: I would note that in the example above `cobj.c` is accessed before `cobj` is fully constructed. It seems to me that even for non-const objects this action is dubious.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Why? Looks valid to me (even if you add a base class to struct C).

Comment: @VJovic: As long as the constructor has not run, the object is not alive yet -- see Sutter's take in [Constructor Failures (or, The Objects That Never Were)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm). If an object is not alive yet, accessing it is dubious. I don't say it is necessarily undefined or unspecified, just that it "smells bad".

Comment: I don't understand the wording. `cptr` is obtained from `this`, but the quote says "**not** obtained" (how else)? Also, this quote means constructor body shall not modify any members, or else behavior will be unspecified for const objects?

Comment: @visitor: The problem is using `cobj` before the constructor returns. The read access is the offending one.

Answer (score 6):

Genuinely `const` objects may be treated by the compiler as legitimate constants. It can assume their values never change or even store them in `const` memory, e.g. ROM or Flash. So, you need to use the non-const access path provided by `this` as long as the object is, in fact, not constant. This condition only exists during object construction and destruction.

Offhand, I think there does not need to be a corresponding requirement for destructors because the object lifetime has already ended and `cobj.c` is inaccessible as soon as the destructor for `cobj` begins.

As Matthieu mentions, it is a strong "code smell" to be accessing an object besides through `this` during construction or destruction. Reviewing C++11 §3.8 [basic.life] ¶1 and 6, it would appear that `cobj.c` inside the constructor is UB for the same reason it is inside the destructor, regardless of the object being `const` or §12.1/14, because its lifetime does not begin until initialization is complete (the constructor returns).

It might be likely to work, but it will ring alarms for good C++ programmers, and by the book it is illegal.

Comment: `C() : c(0) { c=1; }` - so what you are saying is that this is also not valid?

Comment: This seems off-topic: it does not address the fact that `cobj.c` has an unspecified value during the run of `C`'s constructor (even after the initialization's list ran). It also does not address why the behavior would be different (in this regard) between a const and non-const objects.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think I've covered both those issues. The problem is that the compiler can recognize the `cobj.c` access path as having a value that can't change. No matter what function accesses it, a `const` object which does not have a constant value is off limits.

Comment: Ah, I finally got what you were saying with "non-const access path", sorry for being dense.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the quoted rule is to allow the compiler to make
optimizations based on the const-ness of the object.  For example,
depending on optimization, your compiler might replace the second
`cobj.c * 100` in `no_opt` with `i`.  More likely, in this particular
case, the optimizer will suppress the `i` and its initialization
completely, so the code will appear to work.  But this might not be the
case if you also output `i`, before changing `cptr->c`; it all depends
on how agressive the compiler optimizes.  But the compiler is allowed to
assume that `*cptr` is not an alias for `cobj`, because `cobj` is a
const object, where as you modify through `*cptr`, so it cannot point to
a const object without undefined behavior.

If the object isn't const, of course, the issue doesn't occur; the 
compiler must always take into account a possible aliasing between
`*cptr` and `cobj`.